# Function for NSExpression using 'now'

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsfetchrequest

I have an array of `NSDate` from my `ManagedObject` and I want to create a `NSFetchRequest` using an expression that give me only the `NSDate` later then now.

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"eventDate"];
NSExpression *futureDateExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"> now" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write this function. I tried other variations like `SELF > now` or `%@ > now`, `SELF > now()`

All of those gives me `SIGABRT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You will need `NSPredicate`.

2) I'm not sure `now()` in supported in all backends.

3) However you can evaluate now and substitute it as parameter:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventDate > %@", [NSDate date]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:p];
```

Comment: `now()` is a valid function: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-CJBDJCJE

Comment: @DaveDeLong right, it's just backend that does not support it probably. Updated.

Comment: @Lucien we're glad it's working! :) You should mark Krizz's answer as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a comparison in there, you don't have an `NSExpression`, but rather an `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventDate > now()"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:p];
```

---

As it turns out, if you're using this predicate on a SQLite-backed CoreData store, you won't be able to use `now()`.  What you can do instead is this (as [suggested by @Krizz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120169/115730)) :

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventDate > %@", [NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the code but now this is the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression now()'